# WSO2 API manager API not displaying properly

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm deploying WSO2 API manager 2.6.0 with an external MySQL database and I'm trying to have my API's persist when I change my deployment.

Currently I have 2 deployments using the same external database, one local and the other hosted on an AWS EKS cluster. When I create an API on my local deployment, I can only view it on my AWS deployment if I'm logged in to the store, and visa-versa  for my localhost deployment.

The expected and desired behaviour is that all APIs created on both deployments should be displayed on the store no matter if I'm logged in or not, is there any configurations I can change to make the happen?

Here is the doc I used to configure the external database: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Installing+and+Configuring+the+Databases

Comment: Can you confirm you have not shared the local registry db among the 2 store nodes?

Comment: Both my local and AWS deployments are using the same external database, I don't think I'm using a local registry db.

Comment: There must be a node local registry database too. What are the datasources available in your master-datasource.xml and show your registry.xml